# Implicit Polymorphism broken in Hibernate 6.4?

Tags: hibernate, inheritance

Our test of implicit polymorphism is broken in hibernate 6.4.0. It worked in 5.3.
Here it is:

Still using good old hbm.xml :-)

```
    <class name="imppoly.HibBase"
        table="IMPPOLYBASE">

        <id name="id" type="int">
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>

        <property name="baseString" type="java.lang.String" />
    </class>

    <class name="imppoly.HibSub"
        table="IMPPOLYSUB"
        discriminator-value="0">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <discriminator formula="knz" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property name="sub1String" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property name="knz" type="java.lang.String">
                <column name="knz" length="3" sql-type="varchar(3)" />
        </property>
    </class>

    <subclass name="imppoly.HibSubSub"
        extends="imppoly.HibSub"
        discriminator-value="1">
            <property name="subSubString" type="java.lang.String" />
    </subclass>
```

Classes:

```
public class HibBase {

    private int id;
    private String knz;
    private String baseString;

    public HibBase() {//

    }

    public String getBaseString() {

        return baseString;
    }

    public void setBaseString(String aBaseString) {

        this.baseString = aBaseString;
    }

    public int getId() {

        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int aId) {

        this.id = aId;
    }

    public String getKnz() {

        return knz;
    }

    public void setKnz(String aKnz) {

        this.knz = aKnz;
    }
}

public class HibSub
    extends HibBase {

    private String sub1String;

    public HibSub() {

        super();
        setKnz("0"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }

    public String getSub1String() {

        return sub1String;
    }

    public void setSub1String(String aSubString) {

        this.sub1String = aSubString;
    }
}

public class HibSubSub
    extends HibSub {

    private String subSubString;

    public HibSubSub() {

        super();
        setKnz("1"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }

    public void setSubSubString(String aSubSubString) {

        this.subSubString = aSubSubString;
    }

    public String getSubSubString() {

        return subSubString;
    }
}
```

Testcode:

```
    private static void testImplicitPolymorphism(StatelessSession session) {

        try {

            session.createNativeQuery("delete from IMPPOLYBASE").executeUpdate();
            session.createNativeQuery("delete from IMPPOLYSUB").executeUpdate();
            session.getTransaction().commit();

            session.beginTransaction();

            imppoly.HibBase base = new imppoly.HibBase();
            int cnt = 0;
            base.setId(cnt++);
            session.insert(base);

            imppoly.HibSub sub = new imppoly.HibSub();
            sub.setId(cnt++);
            session.insert(sub);

            imppoly.HibSubSub subsub = new imppoly.HibSubSub();
            subsub.setId(cnt++);
            session.insert(subsub);

            session.getTransaction().commit();

            List list = session.createSelectionQuery("from imppoly.HibBase").list();
            if (3 != list.size()) {
                System.err.println("Error 3!");
            }

            list = session.createSelectionQuery("from imppoly.HibSub").list();
            if (2 != list.size()) {
                System.err.println("Error 2!");
            }

            list = session.createSelectionQuery("from imppoly.HibSubSub").list();
            if (1 != list.size()) {
                System.err.println("Error 1!");
            }
```

Meaning:

- HibBase is mapped to table IMPPOLYBASE.
- HibSub is a subclass to HibBase BUT is only mapped to IMPPOLYSUB. Its mapping is NOT related
  to HibBase!
- HibSubSub is subclass to HibSub and is mapped as subclass
  to HibSub.

The test is inserting three instances HibBase, HibSub and HibSubSub.
According to implicit polymorphism the HQL query "from imppoly.HibBase" gives
all three instances in hibernate 5.3
But in hibernate 6.4 the query return 1 instance only.

Looks like a bug to me?